# Can referer header be trusted when using https?

Tags: https, header

I understand that the referer header is trivial to spoof when using standard http. But when using https can you trust the referer or is that potentially faked as well?

Answer (score 6):

No. Using HTTPS changes nothing; the referer can still trivially be spoofed; for example:

```
wget --referer=http://whitehouse.gov/ https://example.com/
```