# How to check client is from swagger ui or not in net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Currently , I have a client and server project with the same source,
so I want to distinguish if the client has to test on my swagger or the client somewhere else so I can process it according to my business.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Let me get that straight: you want your server to behave "differently" depending on whether the request is from the Swagger UI or your "normal" client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caution: It is not normal practice for the server to assume or guess things from the client "metadata" and serve different content based on that as it can be freely manipulated

> Read more:
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent
>
> [Can referer header be trusted when using https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432704/can-referer-header-be-trusted-when-using-https)

For the specific question mentioned. One way that can be helpful is to check the Referer header. Most likely a Swagger Web UI client will issue a normal XHR request from the current page to your server. (Caution: There are different kind of Swagger client. Not only the 'standard' web client) And the Referer header will contain something like this

```
Referer:
https://my-server.com/api/swagger/index.html
```

Sample code

```
    string referer = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
    // Very dangerous code. Change it to match the exact location where you are hosting your Swagger
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(referer) && referer.Contains("/swagger/"))
    {
        // The request was made from Swagger UI.
        // Do something with this information if you want.
    }
```

Again, this can be easily manipulated by the client and/or lead into unexpected issue. Please specify what you are trying to achieve and create another question for that instead

Comment: I have followed your instructions, thank you very much !